# Highchart startR is undefined under N(H, "parts/PieSeries.js", [H["parts/Globals.js"], H["parts/Utilities.js"]] highcharts.js file

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, highcharts, gauge

I am implementing the solid gauge chart in my application.but got stuck due to below highlighted issue of the high-chart file.
Sometime solid gauge chart loads properly but some time it does not because of startR is undefined.

Can someone tell us how to give the own startR value.When I enter the hard coded value at the same place it works fine. ?

is there any solution for this bug ?

[image: Highchart startR undefined]

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue in an online code editor like codesandbox?

Answer (score 0):

Upgradation of Highcharts@8.0.0 will fix the issue